# Japanese Unicode characters not printing in Sphinx Simple-PDF

Tags: unicode, japanese, sphinx, restructured-text

I am a newbie in Latex. I am using [sphinx-intl](https://sphinx-intl.readthedocs.io/en/master/refs.html) to generate my `.po` files and [sphinx-simplepdf](https://github.com/useblocks/sphinx-simplepdf) extension to generate the PDF.

My Sphinx `conf.py` is :

```
locale_dirs = ['locale/']   # path is example but recommended.
gettext_compact = False     # optional.

## Tried this as workaround - But not helping!
latex_engine = 'uplatex'   # Also tried with 'xelatex'
latex_use_xindy = False
latex_elements = {
    'preamble': '\\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}\n',
}
```

My `.po` file looks like:

```
#: ../../user/about.rst:12
msgid "PA-AMR consists of the following main components:"
msgstr "PA-AMRは、以下の主要コンポーネントで構成されています。"
```

I generate the PDF using: `sphinx-build -b simplepdf -D language='ja' . build/`

But the PDF just prints "PA-AMR" from the above `msgstr`. I believe it is not identifying the Japanese Unicode.
If there are Japanese characters after English, then Japanese characters are not printing, and vice-versa.

How to properly get all the characters within the `msgstr` in the PDF? Although the HTML is translating perfectly.

**UDPATE:** Generated the `.tex` file using: `sphinx-build -b latex -D language='ja' . build/`

Below is the `tex` file with contents before `\begin{document}`

```
%% Generated by Sphinx.
\def\sphinxdocclass{ujbook}
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,dvipdfmx]{sphinxmanual}
\ifdefined\pdfpxdimen
   \let\sphinxpxdimen\pdfpxdimen\else\newdimen\sphinxpxdimen
\fi \sphinxpxdimen=.75bp\relax
\ifdefined\pdfimageresolution
    \pdfimageresolution= \numexpr \dimexpr1in\relax/\sphinxpxdimen\relax
\fi
%% let collapsible pdf bookmarks panel have high depth per default
\PassOptionsToPackage{bookmarksdepth=5}{hyperref}

\PassOptionsToPackage{warn}{textcomp}    

\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}    

\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{txtt}   

\usepackage{sphinx}

\fvset{fontsize=auto}
\usepackage[dvipdfm]{geometry}    

% Include hyperref last.
\usepackage{hyperref}
% Fix anchor placement for figures with captions.
\usepackage{hypcap}% it must be loaded after hyperref.
% Set up styles of URL: it should be placed after hyperref.
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{pxjahyper}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{End User Documentation}

\usepackage{sphinxmessages}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}    

\title{PA\sphinxhyphen{}AMR Documentation}
\date{2022年10月25日}
\release{1.3.0}
\author{RR}
\newcommand{\sphinxlogo}{\vbox{}}
\renewcommand{\releasename}{リリース}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Would it be possible to find the `.tex` file that is generated by Sphinx (maybe there is some option to keep intermediate files)? This would help to check if the problem is in that generated file or if the problem is related to how the compiler is executed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Marijn- How to generate the `.tex` file?

Comment: Updated my question with `.tex`, but it must be just a blank template as I am not using any latex.

Comment: Hmm looking into the documentation a bit, it seems that Simple-PDF does not use LaTeX at all, it is intended as an alternative to the LaTeX builder. So that means that this is not a LaTeX issue. From what I can see you should look into `sphinx-build -b latex` instead, with a different builder.

Comment: Thanks for the `.tex` file. It would be better to indeed post the complete file, that makes testing much easier. If the complete file is very big you can try to make it smaller, either by removing things from the `.rst`, or by removing content from the `.tex` _after_ `\begin{document}` (everything before that is potentially relevant).

Comment: I have updated the .tex file contents @Marijn